# Get language parameter inside Zend Paginator ahref urls (clickable links)

Tags: php, pagination, zend-framework2

Here's my current code within an `index.phtml` viewscript:

```
<?= $this->paginationControl($posts,'Sliding','application/partial/paginator', ['route' => 'home','lang'=>'it']); ?>
```

I'd like to pass the `:lang` parameter within this `paginationControl` call so that way the router is notified and the html results show the `it` lang inside the `pagination html ahref code for clickable links`.

I'm not quite sure how to correctly do this.

Here's my route:

```
'home' => [
    'type' => Segment::class,
    'options' => [
        'route'    => '/:lang',
        'defaults' => [
            'controller' => ApplicationIndexController::class,
            'action'     => 'index',
            'lang'       => 'en'
        ],
    ],
],
```

The resulting html from this paginator will show:

`/pp/public/it?page=2`

But it currently shows

`/pp/public/en?page=2`

even when im on the italian version of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on how you setup your paginationControl partial or viewpage script.

The paginationControl parameters:

```
PaginationControl::__invoke(Paginator $myPaginator, $scrollingStyle, $partial, $params);
```

So within your partial or viewpage script for the pagination you are able to access all the stuff you passed to the `$params` parameter, like you would with your parameters you pass from your controller to your view pages or the partial viewhelper.

You could pass a parameter to the partial like the route to use and its route and query parameters.

```
$this->paginationControl(
    $posts,
    'sliding',
    'application/partial/pagination',
    [
        'route' => 'home',
        'routeParams' => ['lang' => 'it'], 
        'queryParams' => []
    ]
);
```

So now within your pagination partial you could use the route, routeParams and queryParams - [Template used - Item pagination](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html#example-pagination-controls).

```
<?php
if (!isset($queryParams)) {
    $queryParams = [];
}
if (!isset($routeParams)) {
    $routeParams = [];
}
?>

<?php if ($this->pageCount): ?>
<div class="paginationControl">
    <?= $this->firstItemNumber; ?> - <?= $this->lastItemNumber; ?>
    <?= $this->translate('of'); ?> <?= $this->totalItemCount; ?>

    <!-- First page link -->
    <?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
        <a href="<?= $this->url(
            $this->route,
            $routeParams,
            ArrayUtils::merge($queryParams, ['query' => ['page' => $this->first]])
        ); ?>">
            <?= $this->translate('First'); ?>
        </a> |
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="disabled"><?= $this->translate('First') ?></span> |
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- Previous page link -->
    <?php if (isset($this->previous)): ?>
        <a href="<?= $this->url(
            $this->route,
            $queryParams,
            ArrayUtils::merge($queryParams, ['query' => ['page' => $this->previous]])
        ); ?>">
            &lt; <?= $this->translate('Previous') ?>
        </a> |
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="disabled">&lt; <?= $this->translate('Previous') ?></span> |
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- Next page link -->
    <?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
        <a href="<?= $this->url(
            $this->route,
            $routeParams,
            ArrayUtils::merge($queryParams, ['query' => ['page' => $this->next]])
        ); ?>">
            <?= $this->translate('Next') ?> &gt;
        </a> |
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="disabled"><?= $this->translate('Next') ?> &gt;</span> |
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- Last page link -->
    <?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>
        <a href="<?= $this->url(
            $this->route,
            $routeParams,
            ArrayUtils::merge($queryParams, ['query' => ['page' => $this->last]])
        ); ?>">
            <?= $this->translate('Last') ?>
        </a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="disabled"><?= $this->translate('Last') ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
```